# Error handling API calls via RestClient

Tags: ruby, http, spotify, rest-client, rescue

I'm using [rspotify](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify/tree/master/lib/rspotify) to gather a list of data from albums names. All the while I've reached Spotify's api rate limit and would now like to create a few fallbacks to wait until the I can search and retry the search in order to not lose the (x) amount of data I've already retrieved.

The gem uses RestClient but the unfortunately when I reach the rate limit I don't get the amount of time needed to wait until I can make another call:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rest-client 2.0.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:223:in 'exception_with_response': 429 Too Many Requests (RestClient::TooManyRequests)
```

The above is all I'm given. The `begin/rescue` statement below doesn't work as when the code fails, it fails entirely without retrying. What am I doing wrong here?

```
begin
  search = RSpotify::Album.search(album[:title])
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse, RestClient::TooManyRequests, Exception => e
  puts e
  retry
rescue e
  puts e
  retry
end
```

Here is how they suggest error handling:

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#response-callbacks-error-handling

Comment: I have not tried that yet but why wouldn't `Exception` catch any of these errors?

Comment: @spickermann For the record, `RestClient::Exception` did not work.

Comment: There is no reason `Exception` would not be rescued. Now that being said, given the Too Many requests I am surprised that this did not just hang up your application indefinitely. Are you sure this is where the issue is actually occurring? and also why is the second rescue there, it doesn't actually do anything since `retry` will start back up at `begin`

Comment: I'm sort of new with `begin/rescue` so you'll have to excuse me when I ask why `Exception` would not be rescued? I'm pretty sure it is. The stack trace ends at this error. The other rescue was simply there due to my inexperience with this atm and also to exhaust my options of possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of maybe throttling, so inside the exception to use
**RSpotify::authenticate("id", "token")** with some of the multiple spotify accounts that I have
and then **retry**

So something like that all put together

```
begin
   album = RSpotify::Album.find(track.first.album.id)
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse, RestClient::TooManyRequests, Exception => e            
   RSpotify::authenticate("id2", "token2")
   retry
end
```